# how to solve the error: syntax error near unexpected token `do'

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

I am trying to read from two files using this way:

```
if [[ $COPY_PREV_DEPLOYMENT == true ]]; then
    echo [$JOB_NAME] Copying old environment variables of $OLD_APP app to the new environment variables of $NEW_APP app...
    cf env $NEW_APP | awk '/User-Provided/,/No staging env variables have been set/'| cut -f1 -d":" | tail -n +2 > env_variables.txt
    cf env $OLD_APP | awk '/User-Provided/,/No staging env variables have been set/'| cut -f2 -d":" | tail -n +2 > env_variables_values.txt
    paste env_variables.txt env_variables_values.txt | while read -r VARIABLE VALUE
    do
        cf set-env "$NEW_APP" "$VARIABLE" "$VALUE"
    done 
    echo [$JOB_NAME] Done.
fi
```

But I am facing this issue

> .....sh: line 61: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
>   ......sh: line 61:`    do ('

can someone help me to solve?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Remove the `()`s?

Comment: do should be after then

Comment: i had to remove () but the same or it will say near "Done"

Comment: How do you run the script? What's on its first line? What version of the shell do you run?

Comment: @choroba i am using Jenkins to run the script, the first line : #!/bin/bash -x and the shell version I dont know how to get it

Comment: `echo $BASH_VERSION`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use `do` after an `if` condition. `do... done` is mostly use in [loops](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html). Also, it doesn't seem like parenthesis would be needed to wrap this single execution statement from the [cloudfoundry api](http://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/set-env.html).

The code might look like this:

```
if [[ $COPY_PREV_DEPLOYMENT == true ]]; then
    echo $JOB_NAME Copying old environment variables of $OLD_APP app to the new environment variables of $NEW_APP app...
    cf env $NEW_APP | awk '/User-Provided/,/No staging env variables have been set/'| cut -f1 -d":" | tail -n +2 > env_variables.txt
    cf env $OLD_APP | awk '/User-Provided/,/No staging env variables have been set/'| cut -f2 -d":" | tail -n +2 > env_variables_values.txt
    paste env_variables.txt env_variables_values.txt | while read -r VARIABLE VALUE; do 
        cf set-env "$NEW_APP" "$VARIABLE" "$VALUE"
        done
    echo $JOB_NAME Done.
fi
```

Comment: There's a `while` after the pipe, so `do` and `done` are perfectly valid. Also, `(...)` is used for subshells, not chaining. BTW, the script works for me without error.

Comment: Sure, I've updated the comment. I'm not familiar with the cloudfoundry cli, so I've left that untouched, just focused on the bash bits

Comment: @choroba thanks for pointing that out. The while loop wasn't there before

Comment: This is the result '+ paste env_variables.txt env_variables_values.txt
+ '[' read -r VARIABLE VALUE ']'
/tmp/....sh: line 60: [: too many arguments
paste: write error: Broken pipe'

Comment: My fault, square brackets are not needed here. I've updated the script